# [ROS2][std_msgs::msg::Int8] publisher and create_publisher

Tags: ros2, publisher, ros-humble

### Version:

Ubuntu 22.04 , ROS2 Humble

### ERROR description

I want to create a publisher that publishes `std_msgs::msgs::Int8` messages, but when I write according to the tutorials in the official document, I get errors:

```
Lock_Stop_pub = this->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::Int8>("/stop", 10);
-----------------------
ERROR:
No matching member function for call to 'create_publisher' 
 clang(ovl_no_viable_member_function_in_call)
node_impl.hpp(73, 7): Candidate function template not viable: no known conversion from 'SentryMaster' to 'rclcpp::Node' for object argument
```

```
rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::Int8>::SharedPtr Lock_Stop_pub;
------------------------
ERROR:
In template: static assertion failed due to requirement 'rclcpp::is_ros_compatible_type<std_msgs::msg::Int8_<std::allocator<void>>>::value': given message type is not compatible with ROS and cannot be used with a Publisher
publisher.hpp(80, 3): Error occurred here
sentry_master.cpp(28, 13): In instantiation of template class 'rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::Int8_<std::allocator<void>>>' requested here
```

The complete minimal program is here

```
class SentryMaster: public rclcpp::Node{
public:
    SentryMaster():Node("sentry_master_node_cpp"){
        Lock_Stop_pub = this->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::Int8>("/stop", 10); 
    }
private:
    rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::Int8>::SharedPtr Lock_Stop_pub;
};
```

Then I found that I can write like this without error

```
auto Lock_Stop_pub = this->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::Int8>("/stop", 10);
```

Write as it, Clang told me the type of `Lock_Stop_pub` is `std::shared_ptr<Publisher<Int8_<allocator<void>>, allocator<void>>>` , but when I change the code, get errors again.

But why???

---

**Added based on comments:**

1. It is worth noting that this situation is only found when writing the message type "std_msgs::msgs::Int8", but this does not happen with other message types such as "geometry_msgs::msgs::PointStamped".
2. Other typical open source ROS2 programs will not report errors
3. if add 'count_(0)' to the code:

```
SentryMaster():Node("sentry_master_node_cpp"), count_(0){
        Lock_Stop_pub = this->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::Int8>("/stop", 10); 
    }
-----------------------
ERROR:
Member initializer 'count_' does not name a non-static data member or base class
```

4. My CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(user_packages)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# Export compile commands for clanged
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(nav_msgs REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include_directories(
  include
)

set(dependencies
  rclcpp
  geometry_msgs
  nav_msgs
)

add_executable(sentry_master src/sentry_master.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(
  sentry_master
  ${dependencies}
)

install(TARGETS 
  sentry_master
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})

install(DIRECTORY launch DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME})

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when
  # a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()
```

Comment: What version of ros2 and what operating system are you using?  Are you able to build https://github.com/ros2/examples/tree/rolling ?

Comment: Can you tell us, what happens, if you add 'count_(0)' to the code?
'SentryMaster():Node("sentry_master_node_cpp"), count_(0)'

Comment: And show us please the content of your 'CMakeLists.txt'

Comment: @Wilhelm , thanks for your patient. Now I add my 'CMakeList.txt' and the error when I add 'count_(0)' to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know the answer, sorry for the rash question.

I forgot to add the header file. Although clang plug-in will automatically add a fake header file for me, it cannot replace the header file I added.

"A fake header file" like this:

```
#include <std_msgs/msg/detail/int8__struct.hpp>
```

but what the program need is:

```
#include <std_msgs/msg/int8.hpp>
```

Comment: Glad you found the answer. Thanks for following up here to help others who find it in the future.

Comment: Then you can accept your own question as valid, so it is marked as "done"

Answer (score 0):

```
no known conversion from 'SentryMaster' to
'rclcpp::Node' for object argument`
```

This leads me to assume that `this` in the first code block is a `SentryMaster`, but `SentryMaster` does not inherit from `rclcpp::Node`.

However it is hard to tell without seeing more of the actual code (preferably a minimal example showing the issue).

Comment: A minimal example like this:

class SentryMaster: public rclcpp::Node{
public:
    SentryMaster():Node("sentry_master_node_cpp"){
        Lock_Stop_pub = this->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::Int8>("/stop", 10); 
    }
private:
    rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::Int8>::SharedPtr Lock_Stop_pub;
};